# Mounting partitions without a password using Udisks2

Tags: linux, fedora, mount

I'm trying to mount some partitions on my hard drive by clicking them in thunar or running `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb6 &` in a script, but I can't find a way for this not to come up with a password prompt.

I am in the groups `<myusername> wheel users`. I wasn't in the `users` group to start with, so i added myself to it in an attempt to make this work.

My fstab looks like this:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Mar 12 19:43:55 2017
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/luks-d7a09ab1-cfa0-4910-ad28-041248fd55ed /                       ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 1 1
UUID=d713df23-90c8-4ed3-9246-9467be868d5d /boot                   ext2    defaults        1 2
/dev/sdb6   /run/media/username/shared/ vfat    noauto,user,exec,rw,async,atime 0 0
/dev/sdb12  /run/media/username/extra/      ext4 noauto,user,exec,rw,async,atime    0 0
```

Really, the whole purpose of this is to mount these two partitions on login without increasing boot time (they are media partitions), so if there's a way to do that in the background then that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK udisks needs a policykit rule to allow an unauthenticated user to mount disks. [As this page](https://www.dynacont.net/documentation/linux/udisks2_polkit_Allow_unauthenticated_mounting/) suggests, just create a file `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks2.rules` containing:

```c
// See the polkit(8) man page for more information
// about configuring polkit.

// Allow udisks2 to mount devices without authentication
// for users in the "wheel" group.
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system" ||
         action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount") &&
        subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! To other searchers, a workaround with different problems is to have passwordless sudo enabled and run the command with sudo.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew M's answer does not work if you have a `pkaction` of version `0.105` or less.
To check `pkaction` version:

`pkaction --version`

> pkaction version 0.105

If `pkaction` version is `0.105` or less, creating the rule `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks2.rules` will not work.
For `pkaction` version `0.105` or less (haven't tested with versions less than `0.105`), create the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-udisks.pkla` with the following content:

`[udisks]`
`Identity=unix-group:sudo`
`Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system`
`ResultAny=yes`
`ResultInactive=no`
`ResultActive=yes`
This allows anyone in the `sudo` group to mount partitions using udisks2 without authentication.

The difference between Forrest Voight's and this answer is that though both of them works, this method does not allow blanket password less authentication for all actions. The password less authentication is only enabled for mounting partitions.

Comment: Worked for me when changing the Action= line to `Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat
`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I could apply permission to udisks with the following setting.

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-udisks.pkla

```
[udisks]
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Reference: https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/mount-internal-partition-without-using-root-password/

Answer (score 0):

Andrew M.'s answer works with newer versions of Ubuntu, but for Ubuntu 17.04 or lower, PolicyKit configuration works differently.

Creating `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-allow-sudo-group-to-do-anything-without-password.pkla` with the following contents:

```
[AllowSudoGroupToDoAnythingWithoutPassword]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=*
ResultAny=yes
```

allows users in the `sudo` group to have blanket passwordless authentication.